# JavaScript function that takes a multidimensional array, flattens it, then returns array values as string in choice order

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, string-interpolation

Having trouble with a certain objective where I have to create a function that takes a multidimensional array and returns a flat array with sentence string values using values from the given multidimensional array. I'm having a hard time iterating through the array and getting it to push the values to a new array. Everything I've tried returns the values in the wrong spots and now it just returns ***undefined***. I'm so lost and frustrated

**Define a function, *zooInventory*, that accepts a multi-dimensional array of animal facts.
*zooInventory* should return a new, flat array of strings. Each element in the new array should be a sentence about each of the animals in the zoo.**

```
let myZoo = [
  ['King Kong', ['gorilla', 42]],
  ['Nemo', ['fish', 5]],
  ['Punxsutawney Phil', ['groundhog', 11]]
];

function zooInventory(zooList) {
  let zooFlat = [];
  let name = [];
  let animal = [];
  let age = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < zooList.length; i++) {
    if (!Array.isArray(zooList[i])) {
      name.push(zooList[i])
    } else {
      animal.push(zooList[i][0]);
      age.push(zooList[i][-1]);
    }
  }
  for (let j = 0; j < name.length; j++) {
    zooFlat.push(`${name[j]} the ${animal[j]} is ${age[j]}.`)
  }
  return zooFlat;
}
zooInventory(myZoo);
/* => ['King Kong the gorilla is 42.',
       'Nemo the fish is 5.'
       'Punxsutawney Phil the groundhog is 11.']
*/
```

Comment: Are you aware of [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)? That method would be useful toward solving this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71623956/javascript-function-that-takes-a-multidimensional-array-flattens-it-then-retur#comment126585147_71623956):

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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)

```js
const myZoo = [
  ['King Kong', ['gorilla', 42]],
  ['Nemo', ['fish', 5]],
  ['Punxsutawney Phil', ['groundhog', 11]],
];

function createSentence (item) {
  const [name, animal, age] = item.flat();
  return `${name} the ${animal} is ${age}.`;
}

function zooInventory (zooList) {
  return zooList.map(createSentence);
}

console.log(zooInventory(myZoo));
```

Comment: I was not aware honestly! That is incredibly helpful! This is an assignment after JUST covering what arrays, multidimensional arrays, and basic array methods are so it kind of threw me for a loop. I didn't think about making and calling on a separate sentence structuring function. I figured I needed to stick to looping through everything. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JosephCorrado Separating concerns is one of the many benefits of [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming). Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment is very specific, so I would go for a very specific solution:

```
let myZoo = [
  ['King Kong', ['gorilla', 42]],
  ['Nemo', ['fish', 5]],
  ['Punxsutawney Phil', ['groundhog', 11]]
];

function zooInventory(zooList) {
  return zooList.map(animal => animal[0] +' the '+ animal[1][0] +' is '+ animal[1][1] +'.')
}

console.log(zooInventory(myZoo))
```

As you can see, you don't need to do anything like flattening if your assignment is exactly this, because you can just concatenate the string reading from nested arrays.

Answer (score 0):

... techniques used ...

- [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
- [Destructuring Assignment / Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring)
- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
console.log([

  ['King Kong', ['gorilla', 42]],
  ['Nemo', ['fish', 5]],
  ['Punxsutawney Phil', ['groundhog', 11]]

].map(arr => {
  const [name, animal, age] = arr.flat();
  return `${ name } the ${ animal } is ${ age }`;
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```